# Pass string value from main into function and vice versa

Tags: string, powershell, function, parameters

I'm a beginner in PowerShell and I was wondering how I can pass strings (or any values) around in functions and from main.
Thank you

```
function RenamePC {
    $username = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username.Split('\')[1]
    Write-Host "Username: " $username
}

function renameAction {
    Write-Host "This is the username" $username
    Rename-Computer -NewName $username -Force
}

RenamePC
renameAction
Write-Host "The new pc name will be" $username
```

Comment: Take a look at [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2#functions-with-parameters)

Comment: Ditto, and have at least function RenamePC **output** the username. BTW. where does variable `$pcname` come from??

Comment: that was a mistake, thanks for pointing that out Theo

Comment: try this: $script:username = (Get-CimInstance...